# Duplicate column name in LEFT JOIN | MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have 2 table ("Alpha" and "Beta") in MySQL. I need to join them. Unfortunately I have error when try next SQL code. I need some advice.

**ERROR:**

```
Duplicate column name 'TIME_KEY'
```

**SQL:**

```
SELECT * FROM Alpha A
LEFT JOIN Beta B ON A.TIME_KEY = B.TIME_KEY
```

**Table "Alpha"**

```
       TIME_KEY      | FIRST_NAME
---------------------|------------
2018-07-01 00:00:00  | Bob
2018-07-01 01:00:00  | Jon
2018-07-01 02:00:00  | Olivia
2018-07-01 03:00:00  | Emily
2018-07-01 04:00:00  | Isla
```

**Table "Beta"**

```
       TIME_KEY      | LAST_NAME
---------------------|------------
2018-07-01 00:00:00  | Johnson
```

I want next result:

```
       TIME_KEY      | FIRST_NAME | LAST_NAME
---------------------|------------|-----------
2018-07-01 00:00:00  | Bob        | Johnson
2018-07-01 01:00:00  | Jon        | NULL
2018-07-01 02:00:00  | Olivia     | NULL
2018-07-01 03:00:00  | Emily      | NULL
2018-07-01 04:00:00  | Isla       | NULL
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong about having multiple columns with the same name. Well... unless you are referring to those names for something, like when creating a view based on the select, or when retrieving values by their column names. I think the problem is related to something else, not described in the question.

Comment: Timestamps as primary keys is a very poor choice. JOIN on timestamp as well. Too risky.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Specify the columns specifically

```
SELECT A.Time_Key, A.First_Name, B.Last_Name
FROM Alpha A
LEFT JOIN Beta B ON A.TIME_KEY = B.TIME_KEY
```

If you want both Time_Key give them alias

```
SELECT A.Time_Key, B.Time_Key as TimeKey2, A.First_Name, B.Last_Name
FROM Alpha A
LEFT JOIN Beta B ON A.TIME_KEY = B.TIME_KEY
```

Comment: Why would it be a problem to have two columns with the same name? Downvoting.